# How to overcome the error `Knowledge insufficient access rights on entity: KnowledgeLanguageConfig`?

Tags: knowledge, cicd, insufficient-privileges

In my CI/CD pipeline I see some strange error:

`Knowledge insufficient access rights on entity: KnowledgeLanguageConfig`.

This is very weird, since I received this error on post merge deployment and every pre merge validation was successful.

When I tried to deploy the same folder manually, it succeeds without issues.

What might be the reason?

I am deploying knowledge settings and trying to add languages definitions.

```
<languages>
    <language>
        <active>true</active>
        <defaultAssignee></defaultAssignee>
        <defaultReviewer></defaultReviewer>
        <name>en_US</name>
    </language>
    <language>
        <active>true</active>
        <defaultAssignee></defaultAssignee>
        <defaultReviewer></defaultReviewer>
        <name>es</name>
    </language>
</languages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CI/CD integration user didn't have `Knowledge` checkbox checked on the user profile and this was the reason why knowledge language settings were not deployed successfully.

When I enabled `Knowledge` checkbox on CI/CD integration user, deployment went successfully.